# Panda's .sum seems to ignore skipna=False if after a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following - would you not expect to see a NaN in the second sum?

```
import pandas as pd
import math
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,math.nan,6],[0,8,9]],index=['a','b','c'],columns=['x','y','z'])
print(a.groupby(['x'],sort=False).sum())
print(a.groupby(['x'],sort=False).sum(skipna=False))
```

In reality, you get the exact same results. Why? Is this a bug? Using Pandas 0.25.2.

Comment: Confirm same output as OP on my end

Comment: Does that also seem not right to you as well?

Comment: Yes! look like not correct, but you can fix it with  `a.groupby('x',sort=False).agg(lambda x : x.sum(skipna=False))`

Comment: even greater magic: .aggregate(lambda x: sum(x)) returns the na.

Comment: haha we are thinking the same way, the challenge is that is very very slow

Comment: Would you like open a issue in github ?

Comment: Probably for the best.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15675

Comment: Thank you. Will track that one. Weird surprise, you'd think this would be well trod.